# How do we create letters with dash over them? (strikethrough or strikeout)

Tags: support, formatting

a) With GNU/Linux OS & Ubuntu in general in text editors

b) Specifically for askubuntu.com as to imply that the text is deleted (edited later)

c) or as an html formatting in a broader sense.

I want to edit something but I would like the old text to be viewed in that form so that people can have an idea on was written before because there are comments on the original version. (I even don't know what that formatting is named. Edit after JorgeCastro's answer: Appearently its called [strikethrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough))

Comment: Markdown (+ Inline HTML) Editing Help: http://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is HTML for this:

```
<s>struck out text</s>
<strike>also struck out</strike>
```

<strike>this is a test</strike>

The Markdown format will allow a lot of different HTML.

Comment: Whitelisted subset of HTML tags supported by the SO engine: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed)

Answer (score 2):

What's the Stackoverflow precedent on strikethrough? I've always seen people just edit directly and the people who respond get a notification anyway and it's more "wiki like".

(I am asking because I find strikethrough hard to read)

Comment: I don't know about the actual examples but the source which @iamsid linked as a comment to @Oli's answer mentions the <strike> tag. In most cases just editing is OK but in some rare cases -especially when there's a discussion traffic between the question/answer and comment(s)- sometimes it doesn't seem fair just plainly editing the body text because then the comment(s) sounds to be meaningless and searching for the history is not easy/practical for everyone for all the times. However, limiting the useage, using that way with care would be fine.

Comment: Most often, strikethrough is not needed and simply overwriting is more elegant. But strikethrough *can* be very useful sometimes, in particular when you want to emphasize wrong/right values or before/after text snippets.